# How can I solve error 'Multiple representations of the same entity'?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am new using JPA and I'm getting an error when trying to insert more than a value into the ParticipantesEntity table.
So ConcursoEntity  has a OneToMany Relation to ParticipantesEntity.

```
ENTITY
------
public class ConcursoEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CONCURSO_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CONCURSO_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "CONCURSO_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
        
    @Column(name = "PREMIO")
    private String premio;
    
    @Column(name = "RUT")
    private String rut;
    
    @Column(name = "FECHA_ACTUALIZACION")
    private Timestamp fechaActualizacion;
    
    @Column(name = "DIRECCION")
    private String direccion;
    
    @Column(name = "COMUNA")
    private String comuna;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<ParticipantesEntity> pticipantes;
    
}



public class ParticipantesEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PARTICIPANTES_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PARTICIPANTES_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "PARTICIPANTES_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "RUT")
    private String rut;
    
    @Column(name = "TIPO_PARTICIPANTE")
    private String tipoParticipante;
        
    
}
```

### ERROR

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple representations of the same entity [cl.bch.cloud.ms.grts.web.entities.ParticipantesEntity#1] are being merged. Detached: [ParticipantesEntity(id=1, rut=216956245, tipoParticipante=PROPIETARIO)]; Detached: [ParticipantesEntity(id=1, rut=156324865, tipoParticipante=AVAL)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [cl.bch.cloud.ms.grts.web.entities.ParticipantesEntity#1] are being merged. Detached: [ParticipantesEntity(id=1, rut=216956245, tipoParticipante=PROPIETARIO)]; Detached: [ParticipantesEntity(id=1, rut=156324865, tipoParticipante=AVAL)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
```

### REQUEST

```
{
   "id":1,
   "premio":"auto",
   "rut":"162332112",
   "direccion":"LOS JACINTOS 374",
   "comuna":"VALPARAISO",
   "participantes":[
      {
        "id": 1,
         "rut":"156324865",
         "tipoParticipante":"AVAL",

      },
      {
          "id": 1,
         "rut":"216956245",
         "tipoParticipante":"PROPIETARIO",

      }
   ]
}
```

I've tried adding a @ManyToOne relation in table ParticipantesEntity, but gives me the same error.

Comment: What do you want to happen? You have two different ParticipantesEntity instances in this JSON, with the same "ID" value of 1, but entirely different other data values. ID means identifier - they need to be unique. If you are trying to insert new values - maybe don't put in ID values at all. The service/database should assign them, not your client.

Comment: You are right the ids where the same so I solve it using different ids:  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "concurso_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 private List<ParticipantesEntity> participantes;